# Including Images in a library with pip install

Tags: python, pip, robotframework, rpa

I'm working on building a python 3.8 based automation library and parts of the library require .PNG files to locate items on the screen.

Is there a way to do this or is this outside the realm of how pip was meant to function?

I've tried pip installing from a git repo as well as from a local directory. The .PNG files are never copied.

I tried putting a **__ init __  py** in the folder containing the images, which makes it create the folder the images are in, but still no images copied.

I've googled the problem but all I've learned is there are pip libraries for PNG, images and extensions.

Comment: see: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

theres lots of ways to do it ...

one way is to make use of `include_package_data` in your setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    include_package_data=True
)
```

and include the datafiles in `manifest.in`

or be more specific

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    package_data={
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        "": ["*.txt", "*.rst"],
        # And include any *.msg files found in the "hello" package, too:
        "hello": ["*.msg"],
    }
)
```

(see also: [pypi setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html))

another option is to store them as base64 encoded strings in a python file))

images.py

```
img1 = "<SOMEB64ENCODED_STR>"
```

most packages allow you to specify images either as raw bytes or as base64encoded data